# WebRTC is failing to connect after ice candidates have been added

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am making a local network chat app in JavaScript, and I am able to connect between two tabs on any single computer, but when I try to connect two computers (on the same wifi network) it fails.

**What works**: Two tabs on the same computer (even if different browser, ex. chrome tab<->firefox tab).

**What doesn't work**: Two different computers (ex. laptop<->desktop), even on same network (if one of the devices is the host of the page).

I have tried to get information from `chrome://webrtc-internals/`, and this seems to be the only major difference, (when it works, the numbers separated by slashes match). (*this is the ice candidate grid for the failing case* vv)

[image: shows STUN requests not being replied to]

Here is logs containing exchanged information between clients during failure:

[image]

Here are the STUN/TURN servers I'm using (in case that's the issue):

```
const RTC_CONFIG:RTCConfiguration = {
    iceServers:[
        {
            urls: ["turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp"],
            credential: "webrtc",
            username: "webrtc"
        },
        {
            urls: ["turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp"],
            credential: "JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=",
            username: "28224511:1379330808"
        },
        {
            urls: [
                "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302",
            ]
        },
    ]
};
```

**EDIT (more information):**

The code continues to fail the same way if the TURN servers, STUN servers, or both are removed.

Here's what it looks like when I connect two tabs:
[image]

Here's what it looks like when I connect two computers on same WiFi network (failure):
[image]

**EDIT 2 (testing progress):**

After setting up a test server with https (and wss for signaling), the LAN connections remain non-functional, while different-network connections work (eg. desktop<->laptop in same room doesn't work, laptop<->phone on cell network does work.)

Comment: One of the TURN servers you are using is taken from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/
The credentials there aren't valid since September 2013.
The same probably applies to the other credential. Run your own turn server and don't copy-paste them from some gist.

Comment: @philipp-hancke you are correct; I tested, and the TURN servers I'm using are missing, but they shouldn't even be necessary over LAN, where this is failing. If I do need a TURN server for LAN connection, how should I set that up?

Comment: I have tested your ICE server setting, and it works. Have you followed the below website to implement the perfect negotiation?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation

Comment: Both my notebook and mobile are on the same network.

Comment: you'll need to describe the candidate in much more details. What gets emitted in onicecandidate, what gets added in addIceCandidate. It is rather odd that the address field is empty in the the working case and only filled for the remote in the non-working case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be about who is connecting with who, and can be solved by making the page host server be a different device than either of the connecting devices.

WebRTC does not seem to like it if the page host is the same device as one of the connection peers.

For clarity, here is what happens when devices in different contexts connect:

```
Network 1 devices:
 host (webpage host)
 localA
 localB
Network 2 devices:
 remoteA
 remoteB

Connections:
host    <> localA  [fails]
localA  <> localB  [succeeds]
remoteA <> remoteB [succeeds]
```

Comment: that is starting to make sense. Without getUserMedia, WebRTC uses the network route that is used to fetch the page as the only address to generate ICE candidates for.

Answer (score 0):

Because the client and server are not on the same machine,
when you access the media from a browser, for security reasons you must install an SSL certificate on your server.

Comment: This implementation only uses a data channel, and even with https, does not work

Comment: You may try to use the following TURN server.
{
                    urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
                    credential: "turnserver",
                    username: "sj0016092@gmail.com",
                }

Comment: The turn server does make it work, but seems unnecessary over LAN. I will try to implement perfect negotiation and if it works, that is a preferable solution to making a TURN server.

Comment: Yes, I have tested my application can work on both my mobile (i.e. 4G network) and my notebook.
You may google "turn server 2021" to find more TURN servers for your testing.

Comment: the result of that Google search should be https://bloggeek.me/google-free-turn-server/ even though the myth of "free turn servers" persists..